# When I pick default dropdown value with javascript, it doesn't trigger change

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a textfield and a date textfield. I am trying to connect them with Javascript, but I encounter a problem. My script is:

```
         <script>
            $("#solDate").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
                    $("#caseStatus").val('In Progress');
                    $("#solvedBy").val('Pick an option');
                    $("#solvedBy").change();
                }
                else if ($(this).val().trim() != '' && $("#solvedBy").val().trim() == '') {
                    $("#caseStatus").val('Solved');
                    $("#solvedBy").val('Please, pick the issue solver');
                    $("#solvedBy").change();
                }
            });
        </script>
```

When date is picked from calendar, it should set a value 'Please, pick the issue solver'. It works perfectly.

Then, if you entered the date incidentally, it should return the previous default value - "Pick an option".

In both cases, a change is triggered.

Then, another trigger is listening for these changes.

```
<script>
        $("#solvedBy").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Please, pick the issue solver') {
                $("#saveBtn").attr('disabled', true);
                $("#slvByValMsg").text('You have solution date and no solver');
            }
            else if ($(this).val().trim() == '' && $("#solDate").val().trim() != '') {
                $("#saveBtn").attr('disabled', true);
                $("#slvByValMsg").text('You have solution date and no solver');
            }
            else {
                $("#saveBtn").attr('disabled', false);
                $("#slvByValMsg").text('');;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

After my troubleshooting, it turns out, that the first if statement on the first script doesn't trigger a change. It may be because it doesn't recognize the default pick option with value ''. I am not sure. Anyhow, when I delete the date from the textfield, the value of the other textfield doesn't change to 'Pick an option', but to ''.

HTML Code:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Solution_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })<sup> 1 </sup>
 <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Solution_Date, new { @id = "solDate", @class = "one", @type = "datetime" })
      <br />
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Solution_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div> 

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Solved_by, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="dropdown">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Solved_by, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SlvBy, "Pick an option", new { @id = "solvedBy" })
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessage("Solved_by", "", new { @id = "slvByValMsg", @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

I know there are probably better ways to do this, but I'm looking for a resolution mainly because I don't know why this change trigger doesn't fire.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: OK, I've added it.  Strangely enough, when I comment the second if statement of the second script, the thing works. But I need the second if statement for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what causes the issue. It turns out that

```
$("#solvedBy").val('Pick an option');
```

Cannot be executed, because this is the default option and the value behind it is ''. This must be messing with the .change() triggers and created havoc in other scripts as well.

I changed it to

```
$("#solvedBy").val('');
```

...and everything works now.